# nightmare.js How to achieve functionality like window.callPhantom() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I have the following code:

```
var nightmare = Nightmare(option)
nightmare
  .goto('some url')
  .evaluate(() => {
    window.callback = function(cid) {
      // do some stuff
      // should screenshot at this point.
    }
  })
  .screenshot('./png.png') //Doesn't get accurate png here
  .end()
```

What I want is add a callback in browser scope, and in browser scope I would call the callback function if it exists at some point. In that callback function I would call main process to take a screenshot at end of the that callback function.

It like something like `window.callPhantom` in phantom.js. But I can't find how to do this in nightmare.js.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sending events from the browser and [listening on the event](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#onevent-callback) in Nightmare might be an option, I have not tried it however. There also is a library [nightmare-custom-event](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-custom-event) to add custom events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`wait(fn)`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#waitfn), fn would be a function that will be executed on the page and return true to stop waiting.

```
var nightmare = Nightmare(option)
nightmare
  .goto('some url')
  .wait(function() { if(something_to_watch) return true; })
  .screenshot('./png.png')
  .end()
```

Comment: But how can I check if my callback function has been evaluated on the page? You mean add a global variable? I have tried this way that nightmare would just hang on.

Comment: Yeah a global variable should work. Maybe the problem is that Nighmare failed to evaluate your page properly ? Try setting a wait in seconds and see if you can render what you expect, else that would mean nightmare cannot process the page correctly.

Comment: I have tried again but still failed. It like `nighmare.evaluate(()=>{window.__screenshotReady = true}).wait(()=>{return window.__screenshotReady})` , still hang out with debug message 'nightmare queueing action "screenshot" +0ms'

Comment: Well, you will have to debug your application. Have a look at [nightmare debugging](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#debugging)

Comment: Yeah, after using debugging it finally works, thanks!

Comment: Can you post a feedback of what was wrong ? So other people can find it.

Comment: Oh, I should do that.

Comment: [Solved] I just forgot call `yield nightmare.end()` at end of the generator function so it doesn't exit.